# How to replace standard error message?

Tags: android, error-handling, crash, forceclose

When application crashes we can see something like *Your wonderful app was stopped*. How can I change this text?

Comment: You can't. Its the Android runtime that detects the crash and produces the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implements `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and assign it to your `Application`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashHandler());
    }
}

public final class CrashHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final UncaughtExceptionHandler handler;

    public CrashHandler() {
        // Uncomment this line if you want to show the default app crash message
        //this.handler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(final Thread thread, final Throwable throwable) {
        // Show pretty message to user

        // Uncomment this line to show the default app crash message
        //this.handler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. :) I'm just wondering if the error then still is send to the dev' console of the playstore?

Comment: Only unhandled error (i.e. crash) will be sent to dev console. If you handle it in uncaughtException() and never call Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(), it won't be sent to dev console.

Comment: will this also help with crashanalytics ?

Answer (score 3):

Those errors are normally shown due to an unhandled exception. If you set an unhandled exception handler at the beginning of the program and then in there show the message you want to view.

I'm not entirely sure however, if after your message has shown whether the default android alert is also shown but this may be what you're after.

Comment: the default is not shown if we are not calling it explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for

[ACRA - Application Crash Report for Android](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

**A synopsis from the site**

> When a crash occurs, you can choose and configure 4 different ways of interacting with the user:
>
> Silent (default): ACRA actions are not visible. The crash report is sent and then the default android crash system does its job (Force Close dialog)
>
> Toast: When the crash occurs, ACRA displays a toast and simultaneously sends the report.
>
> Notification: An optional toast is displayed on application crash, but the report is not sent immediately. A status bar notification is published warning the user that he should send a report. When selected, the notification displays a dialog asking for the authorization to send the report, with an optional user comment.
>
> Dialog: since 4.3.0b1, experimental, allows to display a crash dialog without the need of a status bar notification.

Hope that link helps.

Comment: So you can choose which of four (three really) Android notifications you see when your app fails, but you can't actually cusomise ANY of them. This answers a different question to the one that was asked - "How can I change the text" (i.e. replace it with text of his own choosing).

Comment: yep, it is quite different thing

Comment: Hey sorry about that.. i miss understood the question.. thought you asked how to handle it.. Thanks for correcting it..